# "ORA-00979: Not a Group By expression" with Hibernate HQL

Tags: oracle, hibernate, hql

I am executing the following **HQL query** in an Oracle database:

```
select p, count(e) 
from Entity p 
join p.elementsA l 
join l.elementsB e 
group by p 
order by p.name
```

This works nicely in a MySQL database but when I change the Dialect to Oracle10g it seems it's not using all fields in p to create the group by clause (as required by Oracle) thus producing an "ORA-00979: Not a Group By expression". I understand that by changing the Dialect Hibernate should transform this HQL into a valid SQL sentence for ORacle.

Am I wrong? I am using Oracle10g dialect.

EDIT: Now I've found it does not translate other queries to Oracle dialect. Like this one:

```
select
        e 
    from
        Entity e 
    where
        e.idEntity in (
            :idList
        ) 
    order by
        field(e.idEntity ,
        :idList)
```

Now I understand Oracle does not support order by field sentences but shouldn't HQL be translating it properly to Oracle syntax (i.e. `order by decode(e.idEntity, ...)`)?

Comment: Have you tried to see the sql code that this hql query produces? You can do it using `<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>` in your hibernate.cfg.xml file

Comment: yes, and it's generating the same SQL as when using MySQL dialect. The thing is, in my Oracle environment, there's no reference to MySQL dialect whatsoever.

Comment: It seems that this is a bug that has been unresolved for several years: [https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1615](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1615)

Comment: well that's surprising, since this is not such an unusual case. What's the solution then? Manually specifying all fields?

Comment: You have `p` as an alias for table `Entity` and then you use `p` as in the column list in the `select` statement. On a similar note, your are ordering by `p` (which is actually the alias for the query). Is that just a typo?

Comment: No. That is perfectly valid with HQL.

Comment: Except the order by p, which is not what's in my query sentence

Comment: Might distinct instead of group by work?  Not sure because you're also asking for the count value.